# Show filter value in AgGrid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I'm using a custom `CategoryFilter` for my categories AgGrid:

```
const columnDefs = [
    {
        field: 'categoryId',
        headerName: t('category', { ns: 'common' }),
        cellRendererSelector: (params: ICellRendererParams<IProduct>) => ({
            component: CategoryColumn,
            params: {
                ...params,
                defaultLanguage
            }
        }),
        filter: CategoryFilter,
        floatingFilterComponentParams: {
            suppressFilterButton: false,
        },
    }
]
```

When I filter by category, I can enter the value in the input field, but it's still not showing up under the column's name:

[image]

How do I display the selected category under the "Category" column title?

Answer (score 0):

```
getModelAsString(){
   return "appliedFilters";
}
```

In column category component, `getModelAsString` method should return applied filters as mentioned. if no filter is applied then return null.